# Do you need error handling if your code is typesafe?

Tags: typescript, error-handling

If you write some TypeScript code that is typesafe and is not using third party libraries, do you still need error handling, just because who knows what may happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Not all errors are type-related. For instance, suppose you have a function that does (say) a `fetch` from an endpoint. No amount of type information will change the fact that you need to handle the possibility that the request may fail. Similarly, if notifying a bunch of listeners of an event, no amount of type information will protect you from one of those listeners unexpectedly throwing an error.

I'd say that since I switched primarily to TypeScript, I haven't changed the amount of error handling I do or the level at which I do it (primarily only entry points like event handlers). I have reduced the amount of *type-checking* I do (I don't validate that something is a `number` in a function if the parameter type says it has to be a number, which I might have done in JavaScript), but not the amount of *error handling*.

Answer (score 3):

TypeScript helps verify the consistency of the code base itself, but your system (web app or anything else) has interfaces with the external world. When you specify these interfaces in TypeScript, it **asserts** that the actual interface will comply with its TypeScript description but there is no guarantee at all when the code runs.

Also, TypeScript does not verify the algorithms you are using. As a simple example it won't prevent you from dividing a number by zero. It won't verify that a recursive function has a correct exit condition either, and so on.

As a conclusion, TypeScript helps you raise type-related errors sooner (before even executing your code) but that does not relieve you from doing proper error handling where it's needed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you do. Some errors are not due to unsafe code. For example, an error can occur fetching data from a server.

Comment: Sorry I should have accounted for this possibility in the question, my bad. Say you do not reach any API and there is just no reason why your code should throw errors. Do you still need try/catch? Of course if you have infinite loops or logic errors, your code may throw or misbehave, but these issues are resolved by tests. In production there will be no reason to think the code may throw errors.

Comment: You must try / catch around a function call if that function has the possibility of throwing and exception.

Comment: @anotherOne - I'd argue you probably didn't need that `try`/`catch` in the first place. Whether you have good types for things doesn't really come into whether you need `try`/`catch` around things (which isn't all that often; usually, it's best to let an error propagate).

Comment: @twharmon and T.J. Crowder thank you so much to both of you. So I would not need error handling in the case I was trying to describe. I thought of typesefetyness as a protection from errors because you could not, for example, access a property of a variable yelding `undefined` without typescript complaining.